# Fatal error Form Processor and/or Action Provider

Tags: form-processor, action-provider

I've been using the fabulous Form Processor and Action Provider extensions for several months, and have built up a very useful suite of forms implemented in Google Forms and connected to various form processors in CiviCRM to execute actions. Everything was working great until today. Now, if I even try to access the Form Process menu item I get the error in the screenshot below. I've tried disabling this extension and also the Action Provider extension upon which it depends and then re-enabling both but that hasn't helped. The Action Provider was updated on 3rd March but I don't exactly know when this issue arose. Can anyone suggest any lines of inquiry / resolutions based on the screenshot below? Many thanks, Patrick.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved by disabling form processor and action provider, rolling action provider back to version 1.18, and re-enabling form processor. Apparently the update of action provider on 3rd March broke form processor, at least in my instance of CiviCRM on WordPress.